# How to store lines from a file as a variable

Tags: c++, variables

I'd like to show the employee number name, occupation, and department of employees from a text file called `organisation.txt`, and save them in the variables declared in the class `OrganisationRecord`.

How can I do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#define ORGANISATIONALRECORDSFILE "organisation.txt"
#define HRRECORDSFILE "HR_records.txt"
#define PAYROLLRECORDSFILE "payroll_records.txt"

using namespace std;


class OrganisationRecord
{
private:
public:
    string name;
    string occupation;
    string department;
};

class HRRecord
{
private:
public:
    string address;
    string phonenumber;
    string ninumber;
};

class PayrollRecord
{
private:
public:
    string ninumber;
    double salary;
};

class PayrollProcessing
{
private:
    ifstream inputfile;
    ofstream outputfile;
    vector<OrganisationRecord> OrganisationRecords;
    vector<HRRecord> HRRecords;
    vector<PayrollRecord> PayrollRecords;
public:
    void loadOrganisationRecords(string filename);
    void loadHRRecords(string filename);
    void loadPayrollRecords(string filename);
    void displayEmployeeOfSalaryGTE(double salary);
    //GTE = greater than or equal to
};

void PayrollProcessing::loadOrganisationRecords(string filename)
{
    inputfile.open(ORGANISATIONALRECORDSFILE);

    if (!inputfile)
    {
        cout << "the organisation records file does not exist" << endl;
        return;
    }

        OrganisationRecord _organisationrecord;
        int employeenumber;


        while (inputfile >> employeenumber)
        {   
            while (inputfile >> _organisationrecord.name)
            {
                cout << _organisationrecord.name;
                cout << _organisationrecord.occupation;
                cout << _organisationrecord.department <<endl;
            }

            OrganisationRecords.push_back(_organisationrecord);
        }

}



int main(void)
{
    PayrollProcessing database1;
    database1.loadOrganisationRecords(ORGANISATIONALRECORDSFILE);

    return 0;
}
```

**organisation.txt**

```
0001 
Stephen Jones 
Sales Clerk 
Sales
0002 
John Smith 
Programmer 
OS Development
0003 
Fred Blogs 
Project Manager 
Outsourcing
```

Comment: OK, we can see your code, and what you want to do, but.. What is the question?

Comment: how do I read the data from the file and store it in the appropriate variables?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `inputfile >> _organisationrecord.name` it stops at the first whitespace character. Hence, only `Stephen` will be read and stored in `organisationrecord.name`.

You need to change your strategy a bit.

1. Read the contents of the file line by line. Stop when there are no more lines left.
2. Process each line as you seem fit.

Here's one way to deal with the input.

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline(inputfile, line) )
{   
   // Extract the employeenumber from the line
   std::istringstream str(line);
   if ( !(str >> employeenumber) )
   {
      // Problem reading the employeenumber.
      // Stop reading.
      break;
   }

   if (!std::getline(inputfile, line) )
   {
      // Problem reading the next line.
      // Stop reading.
      break;
   }

   _organisationrecord.name = line;

   if (!std::getline(inputfile, line) )
   {
      // Problem reading the next line.
      // Stop reading.
      break;
   }
   _organisationrecord.occupation = line;

   if (!std::getline(inputfile, line) )
   {
      // Problem reading the next line.
      // Stop reading.
      break;
   }
   _organisationrecord.department = line;

   std::cout << _organisationrecord.employeenumber << std::endl;
   std::cout << _organisationrecord.name << std::endl;
   std::cout << _organisationrecord.occupation << std::endl;
   std::cout << _organisationrecord.department << endl;

   OrganisationRecords.push_back(_organisationrecord);
}
```

Comment: thanks you thank you thank you! just spent all day on this!!