# Reading data from a file and storing it in a variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'd like to show the employee number (without declaring in the class), name, occupation, and department of employees from a text file called `organisation.txt`, and save them in the variables declared in the class `OrganisationRecord`.

How can I pull the data in the text file and save them into the corresponding variables?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#define ORGANISATIONALRECORDSFILE "organisation.txt"
#define HRRECORDSFILE "HR_records.txt"
#define PAYROLLRECORDSFILE "payroll_records.txt"

using namespace std;


class OrganisationRecord
{
private:
public:
    string name;
    string occupation;
    string department;
};

class HRRecord
{
private:
public:
    string address;
    string phonenumber;
    string ninumber;
};

class PayrollRecord
{
private:
public:
    string ninumber;
    double salary;
};

class PayrollProcessing
{
private:
    ifstream inputfile;
    ofstream outputfile;
    vector<OrganisationRecord> OrganisationRecords;
    vector<HRRecord> HRRecords;
    vector<PayrollRecord> PayrollRecords;
public:
    void loadOrganisationRecords(string filename);
    void loadHRRecords(string filename);
    void loadPayrollRecords(string filename);
    void displayEmployeeOfSalaryGTE(double salary);
    //GTE = greater than or equal to
};

void PayrollProcessing::loadOrganisationRecords(string filename)
{
    inputfile.open(ORGANISATIONALRECORDSFILE);

    if (!inputfile)
    {
        cout << "the organisation records file does not exist" << endl;
        return;
    }

        OrganisationRecord _organisationrecord;
        int employeenumber;


        while (inputfile >> employeenumber)
        {   
            while (inputfile >> _organisationrecord.name)
            {
                cout << _organisationrecord.name;
                cout << _organisationrecord.occupation;
                cout << _organisationrecord.department <<endl;
            }

            OrganisationRecords.push_back(_organisationrecord);
        }

}



int main(void)
{
    PayrollProcessing database1;
    database1.loadOrganisationRecords(ORGANISATIONALRECORDSFILE);

    return 0;
}
```

**organisation.txt**

```
0001 
Stephen Jones 
Sales Clerk 
Sales
0002 
John Smith 
Programmer 
OS Development
0003 
Fred Blogs 
Project Manager 
Outsourcing
```

Comment: `How can I do that?` I think you need to rephrase your question to state exactly what the error is

Comment: Ok I've edited the question

Comment: Besides the obvious question of "Why would you want to do that?", the next question is, "What exactly do you mean by 'without declaring in the class'?"  If it's a valid piece of data for that type of record, it really should have its own property/field set up for it...  Also, you may want to rethink your naming convention, the way the classes are named, it seems like you're describing a company, but based on the fields, they're actually describing employee information

Comment: The classes were given to me by my tutor. I am not allowed to edit the current classes or add new ones

Comment: Looks kind of familiar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664447/how-to-store-lines-from-a-file-as-a-variable

Comment: The joys of asking for homework help without trying - you'll get the exact same solution as the other students.

Comment: I've been trying for 3 days...would you like you how many failed solutions I've come to in that time??

Comment: Did you use a debugger and step around the area `while (inputfile >> employeenumber)` Keep stepping a couple of times.  If you really struggle, you could try always putting the line into a string rather than an int so that you can see what you're reading

Comment: you need to go in stages with small increments. Something like this: start with just `int main()` and read just one line from your input file. No classes, no nothing from the above code. Just read with a `std::ifstream`. Then, after that is successful try to read multiple lines. Then after that is successful use a simplified code of the one you are presented where you just set the members of the class with the values read. Then after that is successful try to integrate that with the code you are given.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that will work without any error checking on the input.  Like others have said, you need to read in the file line by line using `std::getline()` because just feeding directly into your variables will cause the input parsing to be delimited by spaces in the text, as opposed to the whole line.

```
OrganisationRecord _organisationrecord;
std::string employeeNumberStr;
int employeenumber;

// without any robust error checking...
while (std::getline(inputfile, employeeNumberStr))
{
    // store employee number string as an integer
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << employeeNumberStr;
    ss >> employeenumber;

    std::getline(inputfile, _organisationrecord.name);
    std::getline(inputfile, _organisationrecord.occupation);
    std::getline(inputfile, _organisationrecord.department);

    // debug print results
    std::cout << "id number: " << employeenumber << std::endl;
    std::cout << "name: " << _organisationrecord.name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "occupation: " << _organisationrecord.occupation << std::endl;
    std::cout << "department: " << _organisationrecord.department << std::endl;

    OrganisationRecords.push_back(_organisationrecord);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Justin!! I now see where I was going wrong. It was driving me crazy